# How to pass formula to another procedure?

Tags: vba, excel

Sorry if this question looks quite random, as I am still learning VBA.

So thing is that my procedure requires input variable for the conditional formatting formula, and I am not quite sure if it requires me to pass on the formula from another procedure.

i.e.

```
Sub Procedure1 (FormulaX As ??)
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Range1").FormatConditions. _
    Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1=FormulaX)
    ...
    End With
End Sub

Sub Procedure2
    Call Procedure1 ("=$A1<5")
End Sub
```

I am very beginner into the VBA and I am quite confused with passing variables for conditional formatting formula. (Maybe I am finding it hard to understand the sentence clearly)

Or if there is any other way to approach this, what will that be?

Edit: Instruction given is "Your procedure definition should require input variables for the conditional formatting formula"

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
Sub Procedure1 (FormulaX As String)
....
```

The instructions simply asks for an input, which can be realized with a String.